# MFC change another monitor resolution

Tags: winapi, mfc

My computer has two monitors, the primary monitor's resolution is 800*600, the other monitor's resolution is 1600*900.

I want to change the second monitor's resolution to 1024*768 in my own application.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to enumerate displays using: [EnumDisplayDevices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609.aspx) - it will give you a name in `DISPLAY_DEVICE::DeviceName` which is needed by following two functions. Once you find your display use [EnumDisplaySettingsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413.aspx) to verify if new resolution is correct then use [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413.aspx) to do actual resolution change

Comment: @dan If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.